# POST Error in Ajax with Laravel, Vue-2, vue-composer

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

I'm working on a learning project in OS X using Laravel, Vagrant, Vue 2 (with vue-resource) and am getting a couple of errors after selecting a video file for upload:

Console Error #1:

```
    POST http://view.app:8000/videos 500 (Internal Server Error)
    (anonymous) @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1068
    PromiseObj @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:198
    xhrClient @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1014
    sendRequest @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1174
    exec @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1129
    next @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1155
    before @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:970
    exec @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1129
    next @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1155
    method @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:984
    exec @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1129
    next @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1155
    body @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:849
    exec @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1129
    next @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1155
    jsonp @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:957
    exec @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1129
    next @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1155
    header @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1004
    exec @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1129
    next @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1155
    cors @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:826
    exec @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1129
    (anonymous) @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1158
    PromiseObj @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:198
    Client @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1122
    Http @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1359
    Http.(anonymous function) @ vue-resource.common.js?2f13:1397
    store @ VideoUpload.vue?1c05:48
    boundFn @ vue.common.js?e881:127
    fileInputChange @ VideoUpload.vue?1c05:40
    boundFn @ vue.common.js?e881:126
    invoker @ vue.common.js?e881:1637
```

Console Error #2:

```
    upload:1 Uncaught (in promise) 
    Response
    body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵    <head>↵        <meta charset="UTF-8" />↵        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />↵        <style>↵            /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */↵            html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}↵↵            html { background: #eee; padding: 10px }↵            img { border: 0; }↵            #sf-resetcontent { width:970px; margin:0 auto; }↵                        .sf-reset { font: 11px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333 }↵            .sf-reset .clear { clear:both; height:0; font-size:0; line-height:0; }↵            .sf-reset .clear_fix:after { display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }↵            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:inline-block; }↵            .sf-reset * html .clear_fix { height:1%; }↵            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:block; }↵            .sf-reset, .sf-reset .block { margin: auto }↵            .sf-reset abbr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help; }↵            .sf-reset p { font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#868686; padding-bottom:20px }↵            .sf-reset strong { font-weight:bold; }↵            .sf-reset a { color:#6c6159; cursor: default; }↵            .sf-reset a img { border:none; }↵            .sf-reset a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }↵            .sf-reset em { font-style:italic; }↵            .sf-reset h1, .sf-reset h2 { font: 20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif }↵            .sf-reset .exception_counter { background-color: #fff; color: #333; padding: 6px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; float: left; display: block; }↵            .sf-reset .exception_title { margin-left: 3em; margin-bottom: 0.7em; display: block; }↵            .sf-reset .exception_message { margin-left: 3em; display: block; }↵            .sf-reset .traces li { font-size:12px; padding: 2px 4px; list-style-type:decimal; margin-left:20px; }↵            .sf-reset .block { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px 28px; margin-bottom:20px;↵                border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;↵                border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;↵                border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;↵                border-right:1px solid #ccc;↵                border-left:1px solid #ccc;↵                word-wrap: break-word;↵            }↵            .sf-reset .block_exception { background-color:#ddd; color: #333; padding:20px;↵                border-top-left-radius: 16px;↵                border-top-right-radius: 16px;↵                border-top:1px solid #ccc;↵                border-right:1px solid #ccc;↵                border-left:1px solid #ccc;↵                overflow: hidden;↵                word-wrap: break-word;↵            }↵            .sf-reset a { background:none; color:#868686; text-decoration:none; }↵            .sf-reset a:hover { background:none; color:#313131; text-decoration:underline; }↵            .sf-reset ol { padding: 10px 0; }↵            .sf-reset h1 { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 15px 28px; margin-bottom: 20px;↵                border-radius: 10px;↵                border: 1px solid #ccc;↵            }↵        </style>↵    </head>↵    <body ondblclick="var t = event.target; if (t.title && !t.href) { var f = t.innerHTML; t.innerHTML = t.title; t.title = f; }">↵                    <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">↵                <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>↵                                        <h2 class="block_exception clear_fix">↵                            <span class="exception_counter">1/1</span>↵                            <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException">TokenMismatchException</abbr> in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68">VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68</a>:</span>↵                            <span class="exception_message"></span>↵                        </h2>↵                        <div class="block">↵                            <ol class="traces list_exception">↵       <li> in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68">VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Founda…ate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest">TransformsRequest</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php line 30">TransformsRequest.php line 30</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest">TransformsRequest</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php line 27">ValidatePostSize.php line 27</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize">ValidatePostSize</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46">CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode">CheckForMaintenanceMode</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 148">Pipeline.php line 148</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 102">Pipeline.php line 102</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php line 149">Kernel.php line 149</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->sendRequestThroughRouter(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php line 116">Kernel.php line 116</a></li>↵       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/home/vagrant/www/view/public/index.php line 53">index.php line 53</a></li>↵    </ol>↵</div>↵↵            </div>↵    </body>↵</html>"
    bodyBlob: Blob
    bodyText: Promise
    Objdata: (...)
    headers: Headers
    ok: false
    status: 500
    statusText: "Internal Server Error"
    url: "/videos"
    get data: get()
    set data: set(body)        
    __proto__: Object
```

Also getting an XHR Error:

```
    TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
    in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) 
    in Pipeline.php line 148
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) 
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) 
    in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))                    in Pipeline.php line 148
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
    at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
    at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
    at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

That CSRF Error makes me first think that I should start there.  I came across this Laravel documentation ([X-CSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)), but just not sure where to put it if this is the problem.

I'm also came across a lot of discussion about vue-resource and how Axios may be a better option.  If this isn't a CSRF issue, is it worth pursuing the switch from vue-resource to Axios?

Lastly, maybe I just need to re-create the project in Laravel to see if that is it.  Is that advisable?  Sorry for the beginner question, but I appreciate any help.

VideoUpload.vue

```
      <template>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">Example</div>

                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <input type="file" name="video" id="video" @change="fileInputChange" v-if="!uploading">

                                        <div id="video-form" v-if="uploading && !failed">
                                    Form
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>

        <script>
            export default {
                data() {
                    return {
                        uploading: false,
                        uploadingComplete: false,
                        failed: false,
                        title: 'Untitled',
                        description: null,
                        visibility: 'private'
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    fileInputChange() {
                        this.uploading = true;
                        this.failed = false;

                        this.file = document.getElementById('video').files[0];

                        this.store().then(() => {
                            //upload the video
                        })

                        //store the metadata
                        //upload the video
                    },
                    store() {
                        return this.$http.post('/videos', {
                           title: this.title,
                           description: this.description,
                           visibility: this.visibility, 
                           extension: this.file.name.split('.').pop() 
                        }).then((response) => {
                            console.log(response.json());
                        });
                    }
                },

                mounted() {
                    console.log('Component mounted.')
                }
            }
        </script>
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.3.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "video.js": "^5.11.6",
    "vue": "^2.2.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

I must be doing something wrong.  I see the csrf-token being referenced in the source.  Adding source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="8WH63seUHqELXf6NFMv5FY6OYHbvYZoVVrBeoQAR">

        <title>View</title>

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="http://view.app:8000/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script>
            window.Laravel = {"csrfToken":"8WH63seUHqELXf6NFMv5FY6OYHbvYZoVVrBeoQAR"};
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://view.app:8000">
                        View
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                                                <li><a href="http://view.app:8000/upload">Upload</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Stephen <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="http://view.app:8000/channel/StephenChannel">Your channel</a>
                                        <a href="http://view.app:8000/channel/StephenChannel/edit">Channel settings</a>

                                        <a href="http://view.app:8000/logout"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="http://view.app:8000/logout" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="8WH63seUHqELXf6NFMv5FY6OYHbvYZoVVrBeoQAR">
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
                <div id='video-upload-component'>
            <video-upload></video-upload>
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="http://view.app:8000/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your "XHR Error", it means that when you're making a **post** request you're not sending CSRF Token.

As per laravel routing rules, middleware comes in action, and among different middleware there is ValidateCSRFToken. Which is checking if you're sending valid CSRF token.

Kindly add that to your AJAX request.

See, if that works.

Comment: I added the upload.blade.php file which extends app.blade.php.  I belief the csrf-token is referenced, but maybe I am doing it incorrectly.  Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: 2 thing which you can do to make sure that csrf token is been passed is, 1. see the view source of your code and see if csrf token html element is in between `<form>...</form>` 2. Check XHR section when you do inspect element.

Comment: I posted the source.  Since I am only selecting the file for upload, the error is  occurring before I get the UID in XHR.

Comment: I don't know what UID is, also when you make a post request can you check parameter section for that request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the CSRF token.

Add this in the HEAD element:

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

If you use jQuery:

```
<script>$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });</script>
```

Comment: Where would I put that $.ajaxSetup line?

Comment: You can put this in the page where you want to use the ajax logic, inside of an script element